# How to override a rails generator template in a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, templates, rubygems, generator

When you want to override a generator template (without replacing the generator itself), in Rails 3 you can just drop files in appropriately named places in lib/templates and Rails will find them.

What if you want to do this with a gem?  I'm trying to take my team's standardized scaffold format and gemify it so we can share it in all projects and update it easily, rather than copy files into lib/ in every project.   This works fine for the cases where I've created a new generator; I hook into it with config.generators in application.rb and Rails finds it.   But when I drop template files into lib/templates in the *gem*, Rails finds its own default templates first, and renders them instead of mine.  I think the search order is RAILS_ROOT/lib/templates, RAILS_GEMS/lib/templates, OTHER_GEMS/lib/templates.

What's the solution?   I'm not finding much docco on this, and code-diving through Rails hasn't presented an obvious solution.   Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We figured this out.   the generators config has a 'templates' variable that lists search paths for templates.   The problem is indeed that it searches this array in order until it finds a match, so templates in your app or in Rails will get found before templates in your gem.

The solution is to have your gem's Railtie put the templates path onto the *beginning* of the array of template paths.  It looks like this.   This file is in [GEM]/lib/my_gem.rb.  The templates are parallel to it in [GEM]/lib/templates/.

```
module MyGem
  class Railtie < Rails::Railtie
    config.generators do |g|
      g.templates.unshift File::expand_path('../templates', __FILE__)
    end 
  end
end
```

If the templates have a path inside [GEM]/lib/templates that matches the path of the default template you are overriding, this should work.   For example, if you've done this and you create [GEM]/lib/templates/active_record/model/model.rb,  it will override the default AR model template.

No monkeypatching of the generators required.

**EDIT:** Note that since this answer was originally posted, "config.generators" has been removed from Rails. Use `config.app_generators` instead as per pixelearth's answer below.

Comment: Can't get this to work. What am I doing wrong? I have the above file in `[GEM]/lib/my_gem.rb` (modified slightly as per @pixelearth's answer), a model template in `[GEM]/lib/templates/active_record/model/model.rb`, and the line `s.files = ["lib/my_gem.rb"] in my `my_gem.gemspec` file... but if I create a new rails app, include and install `my_gem` in the Gemfile, then generate a new model, it still uses the default model. Is there a step I've missed?

Comment: Ahhh, got it - I needed to include the template file in the gem by adding it to `files` in the gemspec.

Answer (score 11):

Update: IdahoEv has the right answer, but this code, as of 3.1 produces the following deprication warning:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: config.generators in Rails::Railtie is deprecated. Please use config.app_generators instead.
```

So use this instead:

```
module MyGem
  class Railtie < Rails::Railtie
    config.app_generators do |g|
      g.templates.unshift File::expand_path('../templates', __FILE__)
    end 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem using rails 4.1.5. And here is assembled puzzle solution.

First of all create Railtie in your gem [like this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Railtie.html).
Keep in mind config.generators is deprecated and [thalespf`s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24320663/3134155).

```
module SomeGem
  class Railtie < Rails::Railtie
    config.app_generators do |g|
      g.templates.unshift File::expand_path('../../templates', __FILE__)
    end
  end
end
```

Works like a charm!

UPD. I have tried to create a gem with templates only and use it within Rails::Engine. But it requires this:

```
# lib/your_engine/engine.rb
require 'your_gem_with_generator_templates' # Loads Railtie
```

Comment: You can override templates from other gems in this way too.  ```your_gem/lib/templates/coffee/assets/javascript.js.coffee```

Answer (score 1):

As for rails 4 and rails engine I'm able to do this as:

```
module MyEngine
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace MyEngine

    config.generators do |g|
      g.templates.unshift File::expand_path("../templates", File.dirname(__FILE__))
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Only the path '../../templates' in g.templates.unshift File::expand_path('../../templates', _ *FILE* _) worked for me. Im in rails 3.2

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's struggling with this, I just got a very basic gem working using the other answers here which you can see for an example: [templates](https://github.com/headstock/templates)