# Rails 3 Generator custom templates with Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, generator

When using the rails generators with an Rails::Engine, it does not seem to pick up any template files that are put into the lib dir. As instructed here

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#customizing-your-workflow-by-changing-generators-templates

Right now I have

```
 lib/templates/rails/scaffold_controller
```

I have also tried

```
 lib/my_engine/templates/rails/scaffold_controller
```

Has anyone else tried this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that this is not supported for Engines

In a Rails app the Finisher takes care of adding this to the path

```
module Rails
 class Application
   module Finisher
    include Initializable

    initializer :add_generator_templates do
      config.generators.templates.unshift(*paths["lib/templates"].existent)
    end

 ......
```

So this must be done in the Engine config in order for this to work.

```
module MyEngine
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    config.generators.templates.unshift File.expand_path("lib/templates", root)
  end
end
```

Is this a bug or the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Above answer (by stellard himself) doesn't fix my case in Rails 3.2, but [How to override a rails generator template in a gem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666595/how-to-override-a-rails-generator-template-in-a-gem)  fix it.  Just pointing out for the person like me.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `rails g generator MyGenerator` in the root path of an Rails 3.2 engine you'll get something like this:

```
class MyGenerator < Rails::Generators::NamedBase
  source_root File.expand_path('../templates', __FILE__)
end
```

which doesnt pollute your `Engine` class and is much more localized to the generator.